# Header name issue is coming in jquery export html data table downloaded excel sheet in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am exporting an Excel sheet in IE. The header name is not coming through correctly in the downloaded sheet. In other browsers it's working fine. The excel sheet header name is a Spanish word. Please help on this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("HELLO")
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {
    var $headers = $table.find('tr:has(th)'), 
        $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

        // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
        // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '","',  
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"';

    // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
    var csv = '"';
    csv += formatRows($headers.map(grabRow));
    csv += rowDelim;
    csv += formatRows($rows.map(grabRow)) + '"';

    // Data URI
    var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,'+ escape(csv);
    //var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

    // For IE (tested 10+)        
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
         var blob = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(encodeURI(csv))], {
             type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8,"+ escape(csv)
         });
         window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
     } else {
        $(this).attr({
            'download' : filename,
            'href' : csvData
            //,'target' : '_blank' //if you want it to open in a new window
        }); 
    }
```